# Replace literal at HTML using Unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a series of scripts declared in an HTML with the following format:

```
xxx.jfhdskfjhdskjfhdskjfjioe3874.bundle.js
```

The part between the periods is a dynamic hash, but it will always be an alphanumeric with the same positions. My problem is that I need to dynamically modify that hash, with the new generated files, which are in the same directory as the HTML itself. Is there a clean way to do it in Unix with a script?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Of course there's a clean way to do it!  You just generate the new hash and rename the files appropriately!

Answer (score 0):

You must be more specific: You want to generate new hashes for all scripts in this directory or need just a tool to change one by one basis? where do you get new hashes from? Below I attached simple script to change the part between first and second period sign. Script should be called with old name as first argument and new hash as second argument. It could be compressed to just one line but I used variables for clarity.

```
#! /bin/sh
OLDNAME=$1
NEWHASH=$2
NEWNAME=$(printf "%s" "$OLDNAME" | sed "s/^\([^\.]*\)\.[^\.]*\.\(.*\)/\1\.$NEWHASH\.\2/")
echo $NEWNAME
```